# How can I create a Javascript alert from the input values of the form a user interacts with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, alert

I want to create a dynamic alert from a specific input value within each form. I have many forms on a page. Each alert needs to be slighly different. I am using two of the forms input values to produce the custom message. `<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size">` & `<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Color">`. I have the alert working for the first form on the page, but after the second form, my alert does not match the selected input value of that form. How can I target a specific instance of these input values within the form a user interacts with?

Here is a simplified version of my code showing only two forms:
[example on - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesigns/7YJ63/4/)

```
<form method="post" class="list1">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size">
<select name="os0">
<option value="">-- Choose a Size --</option>
<option value="Short">Short</option>
<option value=" Medium">Medium</option>
<option value=" Long">Long</option>                             
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Color">
<select name="os1">
<option value="">
-- Choose a Color --
</option>
<option value="ivory">ivory</option> <option value=" black"> black</option> 
</select> 
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" class="catalog">                    
</form>
<!-- seconed form start --> 
<hr />
<form method="post" class="list2">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Option">
<select name="os0">
<option value="">-- Choose a Option --</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>                             
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Accent Color">
<select name="os1">
<option value="">
-- Choose a Choose a Accent Color --
</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="yellow">yellow</option> 
<option value="orange">orange</option>   
</select> 
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" class="catalog">                    
</form>
```

​​
And my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var size_x = $("input[name='on0']").val();
    var color_x = $("input[name='on1']").val();

    function popWarning() {
        if ($("select[name='os0']").val() === "") {
            alert('Please choose a ' + size_x);
            return false;
        }   
        if ($("select[name='os1']").val() === "") {
            alert('Please choose a ' + color_x);
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("input.catalog").click(function() {
        popWarning();
    });​
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you expect the script to know which form (and therefore elements with the same `name` attribute) you're talking about without specifying it? Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function popWarning(obj) {
        var $form = $(obj).closest("form");
        var size_x = $form.find("input[name='on0']").val();
        var color_x = $form.find("input[name='on1']").val();
        var sel_os0 = $form.find("select[name='os0']");
        var sel_os1 = $form.find("select[name='os1']");
        if (sel_os0.val() === "") {
            alert('Please choose a ' + size_x);
            return false;
        }   
        if (sel_os1.val() === "") {
            alert('Please choose a ' + color_x);
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("input.catalog").click(function() {
        popWarning(this);
    });
});
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7YJ63/6/

This way, `popWarning` is able to grab the parent form from the `input.catalog` that triggered it by click, via `obj` (`this` passed in). Then, all elements/values are found with `find` because you know that the elements you're looking for are a descendent of the form.

Comment: Ugh, that's a bit heavy don't you think?

Comment: @Madbreaks How is it heavy? How else will the script know to grab the elements/values from which form?

Comment: Thanks @Ian. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Reference the form and use that as context.

```
function popWarning(form) {

    var size_x = form.find("input[name='on0']").val();
    var color_x = form.find("input[name='on1']").val();
    var size = form.find("input[name='os0']").val();
    var color = form.find("input[name='os1']").val();

    if (size  === "") {
        alert('Please choose a ' + size_x);
        return false;
    }

    if (color === "") {
        alert('Please choose a ' + color_x);
        return false;
    }
}
$("input.catalog").click(function() {
    popWarning( $(this.form) );
});​
```

Let us pass in the reference to the button since that seems to be the breaking point.

```
function popWarning(button) {

    var form = button.get(0).form;
    var size_x = form.find("input[name='on0']").val();
    var color_x = form.find("input[name='on1']").val();
    var size = form.find("input[name='os0']").val();
    var color = form.find("input[name='os1']").val();

    if (size  === "") {
        alert('Please choose a ' + size_x);
        return false;
    }

    if (color === "") {
        alert('Please choose a ' + color_x);
        return false;
    }
}
$("input.catalog").click(function() {
    popWarning( $(this) );
});​
```

Comment: You should add context selector in condition too:  if ($("select[name='os0']",form).val() === "") {...}   http://jsfiddle.net/7YJ63/5/

Comment: @roasted, You can use context selector, but it is a known fact it is slower than find()

Comment: Ya but its not what im talking about, see my jsfiddle

Comment: Ok This worked too and seems much simpler then @Ian example. Thanks @epascarello!

Comment: Does this actually work? The `if` statements don't even match up and use the `<select>` elements like originally stated. This is no "simpler" than mine, it just does the same thing (incomplete, in this case) in a different workflow. It also passes the jQuery object of the `<form>` which means you won't have a reference to the originally clicked element in `popWarning` (in case you ever need it) so that's up to the OP

Comment: that pass in the button reference to the popWarning function. It is not that hard. lol

Comment: @Ian - This example worked on my JSFIDDLE example but when I applied it to my local code it failed to work. No alert was fired.

Comment: @epascarello That was the least important point of my comment

Answer (score 0):

You have two selects with the name `os0` and two with the name`os1`. That is the root of your problem.

The `if` statements do not pass once the first form is completed because the first DOM element with the name `os0` has already been completed. Change the name to `os2` or something similar and do unique `if` conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the values because they are specific to a  PayPal cart. Could give each of these selects its own class?

Comment: No need to modify the HTML, just change the Javascript to select the right elements...

Answer (score 0):

> I have the alert working for the first form on the page, but after the second form, my alert does not match the selected input value of that form.

That's not the problem, really.  Try your JSFiddle, select a size, then click the color "add to cart" button.  You'll see the correct message.  The problem is that your click handler says "if size is empty, say size, otherwise if color is empty, say color".

I would rewrite your `click` event listener and scope it by its form, something like:

```
$('#sizeForm input.catalog').click(function(){
    var form = $(this).parents('form');
    ...
});
```

...etc.  That should make it easy to determine which form was clicked.  Or possibly easier:

```
<input class="catalog size" ... />

$('input.catalog.size').click(function(){popWarning('size');});
```

...which could be more slick/dynamic so that you could handle all the forms in a single handler...but that's maybe overkill of an answer for the nature of your question.

Anyway.  Good luck.

Comment: The problem is exactly as the OP explained. Try submitting the second form as empty...it refers to the original form. But your solution is good

Comment: @Ian did you actually *try* what I suggested in my 2nd sentence?

Comment: I did actually _try_ why you said. And I agree it "works". But as soon as you attempt to submit the second form, it doesn't refer to its own elements...which is what the OP said is the problem...which is the point of the whole question.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. Apologies, I misunderstood what you meant

Answer (score 0):

I think you can adhere more to DRY and elegance if you use the `this` keyword to iterate over the select lists with JQuery's `each()`. Something along these lines:

```
  $("input.catalog").click(function() {
      form = $(this).parent();
    select = form.find("select");
      message = '';
      select.each(
          function(){
              if ($(this).val()=='') {
          number = $(this).attr("name").substr(-1);
          message+= $("input[name=on" + number + "]").val() + " ";
            }
          }
      );
      if (message!='') {
      console.log("Please select the following: " + message);
          return false;
      }
});​
```

Comment: How is this any different than using the same `name`?

Comment: he is NOT using the same name, and rightfully so. You can't use the same `name` for two elements in the same form, and even between forms a different name can serve as a unique ID

Comment: I understand they aren't using the same name, but they are between forms (which is what I meant)...I guess you meant the same class everywhere...which I don't know what you're talking about, but setting the same class for all hidden fields won't help in any way. It doesn't allow the OP to identify which form the **specific** hidden fields are apart of. And it doesn't help the OP identify which form to be using. Unless you provide an example of what you're talking about, this doesn't make sense